# How to display image on a servlet or jsp which is located in my local drive?

Tags: jsp, servlets

My image is placed in C:/UploadedFiles/IMG.JPG and i want to display it on a JSP but i am unable to do it. Please give me a solution ASAP. I have tried but still its not working. I don't know if there is any linkage problem. I am using NetBeans.

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
OutputStream os =response.getOutputStream(); 
FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\pictures\\aayush.JPG"));
byte[] buf= new byte[2048];
int ch=in.read();
while(ch >= 0){
 os.write(buf);
ch=in.read(buf);
}
in.close();
 os.close();
```

Comment: @AayushDid you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're not reading correctly. You start by reading 1 byte, but writing the whole buffer. Then you read bytes in buffer, but don't know how many, and yet you still write the whole buffer.

Do yourself a favor, and use a method that does all that for you: [Files.copy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

Comment: I guess it just show an image in the html, i understand like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is **servlet class** *doGet*

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("imagePath", request.getContextPath() + "/image/test.jpg");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

this is **index.jsp** where you show your image

```
<%@ page
    language="java"
    contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="${imagePath}" />
</body>
</html>
```

And your ***image*** folder should under **WebContent( this deirectory is the ContextRoot)/image/test.jpg**